# Entity Framework Code First without modelBuilder.Configuration or runtime modify modelBuilder.Configuration

Tags: dynamic, runtime, entity-framework-5, code-first

I am new to Entity Framework and I have created class derived from DbContext with following example.

public partial class StudentdbContext : DbContext{

```
     public StudentdbContext()
         : base("Name=StudentdbContext"){
     }       
     public DbSet<student> students { get; set; }


     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){           
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new studentMap());         
     }
```

}

now runtime I am adding another entity called "StudentInfo" with code studentdbContext.Set<"StudentInfo">() , but how can I add "StudentInfoMap" to modelBuilder.Configuration runtime ? Is is possible to use Code First Entity Framework without map object such as "EntityTypeConfiguration" and "EntityTypeConfiguration" ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either use a [Configuration](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/11/28/composing-entity-framework-fluent-configurations.aspx) type, or define the mapping directly in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){           
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new studentMap());         

     modelBuilder.Entity<StudentInfo>() 
           .HasRequired(...)
           etc
 }
```

Comment: I guess this is one of the unwanted limitation of Entity Framework. If they have api to set entity runtime then if would be nice if they have provided api to changed modelBuilder.configuration runtime. It gets more complicated when database has lots of tables and eventhough you are not using them all , still you end up adding all the tables in modelBuilder.Configuration if are dynamically loading "EntityTypeConfiguration" class to modelBuilder.Configuration